# Why the error comes out as missing { before function body?

Tags: javascript

I have both curly brackets but it keeps giving me this error. Is it lacking of something?

```
outerDiv.ondragstart = function()
{ 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "this error". What is it exactly?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, the error is in the title: missing { before function body

Comment: Post the actual error..."this error", "syntax error" isn't helpful, especially when the above code has NO error!

Comment: We understand that, but what does the error literally state?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Can you add some more context? Which line does the error appear in?

Comment: Who is downvoting every answer to this question?

Comment: Your code is Ok, the error should be in other place. You can use this site to help you to find the problem http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: CAn we see more code?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst the error is in the title. Take some time to read the whole thing.

Comment: It just points at the before the () and then said that it is a syntax error: missing { before function body.

Comment: @jlbruno Because `missing { before function body` provides all the necessary context, correct?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst all the context? No. But you asked twice what the error was, and the question does contain the error.

Comment: why don't you just define the function inside the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your code:

```
outerDiv.ondragstart = function(){ 
    return false;
}
```

What is your full code? Try using eventListeners, like this:

```
outerDiv = //selector like document.getElementById()
outerDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", function(){return false;}, false);
```

Comment: but what is the false at the end for?

Comment: @user2963724 - If this solve your problem then accept it as the right answer.

Comment: it said wait for 2 minutes

Comment: @user2963724 here is an explanation [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks! I just started learning javascript so not too good in clearing errors.